# Need some help with formatting on iOS keyboard

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, keyboard-shortcuts

When typing a question/answer on the site, we get this nice bar above the input box:

[image: edit bar]

It helps do quick things like format code and whatnot. As it stands, there's nothing like that on the iOS app. For some things, it's not a huge deal. If I really want to, I can hit the space bar a bunch of times and get what I need (though who would want to write that much code on their iPhone is beyond me). Where the real problem comes in is with things like the ` (back tic) key. There isn't one on the iOS keyboard and (at least without jailbreaking) I don't know of a workaround to make this work.

To be fair, this problem isn't just for the iOS app. This is also a problem when I'm using the regular site, but it's become more of an issue since I'm more likely to respond now that I have a specific app. Can we get some sort of augmentation for the default keyboard?

Comment: There apparently is one. I got schooled on it too. Tap `123` (bottom-left of alphabet keyboard), then hold down on `'` (apostrophe, next to backspace). The far left of that submenu is backtick

Comment: Ah. Didn't know that was there. That's helpful, but my general point still stands. It would be nice to have some shortcuts.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. **image** followed by **code indent** being the top two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Soo...* this is on our list but not a top priority so we don't really have a timeline.  That said, it is an **interesting** problem and some characters are `annoying` to type so I've added an experimental implementation for a couple of them.

```
If you select text in the next build
and tap through the context menu,
you should see three basic formatting
options.  This is not the final design.
```

### Update

Done.